# Clone VSTS Build Definition in C#

Tags: c#, tfs, build, azure-devops, tfs-sdk

I'm using BuildHttpClient's .GetDefinitionAsync and .CreateDefinitionAsync to clone a VSTS Build Definition. This works fine but I'd like to create the build defs in a different folder, other than the root folder of the project. I can add a folders via the "Manage Folders" link web but how can I do this programatically?

I've tried the following:

```
    buildDef = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BuildDefinition>(json);
    buildDef.BuildNumberFormat = buildNumFormat;
    buildDef.Name = newBuildDefName;

    Uri tfsURI = new Uri(CollectionReleaseURL);
    buildDef.Url = tfsURI.ToString();
    await buildClient.CreateDefinitionAsync(buildDef, project);
```

Where the Collection release is the path:
CollectionReleaseURL = @"http://my.tfs.server8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Project/Product/Release";

but when I run the program it just puts the new build def in the following folder:
@"http://my.tfs.server8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Project"

How can i clone the build def to the ../Product/Release folder?

**UPDATE: I'm using the following to Clone the build def but it is NOT copying the Build Steps! Anyone know why that is?**

```
private static async Task CloneBuildDefAsync(int buildDefId, string newBuildDefName, string buildNumFormat, string sourceControlPath, string URLpath)
{
    var buildClient = createClient();
    var buildDef = (await buildClient.GetDefinitionAsync(project, buildDefId)) as BuildDefinition;

    buildDef.Project = null;

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(buildDef);
    json = json.Replace(sourceControlMainline, sourceControlPath);
    buildDef = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BuildDefinition>(json);

    buildDef.BuildNumberFormat = buildNumFormat;
    buildDef.Name = newBuildDefName;
    buildDef.Path = URLpath;

    await buildClient.CreateDefinitionAsync(buildDef, project);
}
```

Seems to copy everything but the build step, everything else is cloned and updated perfectly:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to set the [Path property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#request-body) to the folder you want.

**An example of the clone in PowerShell:**

```
$uri = 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}'

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -UseDefaultCredentials
$result.path = '\NewFolder\Location'
$result.name = "Testing"

$body = $result | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 7

Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -uri 'https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=4.0' -UseDefaultCredentials -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json'
```

**Creates a build folder structure like this:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Matt - I ended up using your solution. I'm using this to automate the creation of a branch in source control and cloning the Mainlines build defs to the branch, also going to create a "Create Release" build def that will call this powershell script. Works like a charm. Now I'm going to create a powershell script to create the source control branch since I've written that in c# as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client you may just set Path:

```
BuildDefinition cpBuild = BuildClient.GetDefinitionAsync(teamProjectName, 8).Result;

BuildDefinition build = new BuildDefinition();
build.Path = "New Build Folder";
build.Name = "new Build";
build.BuildNumberFormat = cpBuild.BuildNumberFormat;
build.Repository = cpBuild.Repository;
build.Process = cpBuild.Process;
var newBuild = BuildClient.CreateDefinitionAsync(build, teamProjectName).Result;
```

Comment: When I try this, which I had tried before I get the following: 'BuildDefinition' does not contain a definition for 'Path' and no extension for 'Path'...

Comment: I use the last version of [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/15.131.1) 15.131.1

Comment: Awesome, thanks Shamrai. Once I upgraded the .Client from 14.89.0 to 15.131.1 I was able to set the path...thanks.

Comment: I've updated my question - do you know why the build steps are not copied?

Comment: Your example works fine for me (except I do not use json replace). But I can not find the build section in my json, I see the Process section. Also Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.BuildDefinition does not contain the build member.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to accomplish this using:

https://gist.github.com/HockeyJustin/c1cb4e543806c16cab6e2c2322f5d830

```
$thisBuildDef.Name = $Clone_Name
$thisBuildDef.path = $BuildDefURL  # Relative to the Project name; like "Release/2019"
$thisBuildDef.buildNumberFormat = $BuildNumberFormat

# Update source control path to new branch
$defAsJson = $thisBuildDef | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
$defAsJson = $defAsJson.Replace($sourceControlMainline, $sourceControlBranch)

$Uri = "$(TFSCollection)/$(TFSProject)/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=2.0"

$newBuildDef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method Post -Body $defAsJson -ContentType "application/json" -ErrorAction Stop
```