# Update build definition using Azure DevOps REST API in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, build-definition, build-triggers

I'm attempting to update my build definitions in Azure DevOps using the REST API via a PowerShell script...

```
$header = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))}
$definitions = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://devops.domain.com/Collection/Project/_apis/build/definitions" -Method GET -Header $header
$branchNames = 'master', 'feature'

ForEach ($definition in $definitions.value) {
    $definition | Add-Member -NotePropertyName triggers -NotePropertyValue (@{ triggerType = 'continuousIntegration'; branchFilters = $branchNames | % {"+refs/heads/$_/*"} }) -Force

    $body = $definition | ConvertTo-Json
    Write-Host $body

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://devops.domain.com/Collection/Project/_apis/build/definitions/$($definition.id)?api-version=5.0" -Method PUT -ContentType application/json -Body $body -Header $header
}
```

It's not particularly clear from the [Azure DevOps documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) how I should update the build definition using this method, but the above results in the following error:

> Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name:
>   **definition.Repository**","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

This is where I'm wondering if I'm barking up the wrong tree as this should surely be simpler (I found a simple solution on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54981430/197591) for creating a new build definition). In fact, all I want to do is update the trigger branch filters.

How do I achieve this using PowerShell and the REST API?

Comment: Try to add `-Depth 10` to `$body = $definition | ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Nope, doesn't change anything.

Comment: If I did it: `$body = $definition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10` I didn't get your error (but the triggers didn't update also, but it another issue.. you need to pass them correctly)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, the error occurs on the `Invoke-RestMethod` call. But the question is, how do I update the trigger branch filters using PowerShell and the REST API? It's not another issue, it's part of the issue.

Comment: I understood, I succeeded to update the triggers :) check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the definitions received from the [list method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) cannot be used directly with the [update method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0). This is quite clear in the list response type [`BuildDefinitionReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#builddefinitionreference) which doesn't include properties such as `triggers`. The definitions must be obtained from the [get method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) using the definition IDs from the [list method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0). This returns a [`BuildDefinition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#builddefinition) which does indeed have the `triggers` property. This can then be modified and passed to the [update method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0).

This is the working code:

```
$header = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))}
$definitions = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://devops.domain.com/Collection/Project/_apis/build/definitions" -Method GET -Header $header
$branchNames = 'master', 'feature'

ForEach ($definition in $definitions.value) {
    $definitionToUpdate = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$($collection)$($project.name)/_apis/build/definitions/$($definition.id)" -Method GET -Header $header
    $trigger = $definitionToUpdate.triggers | Where {$_.triggerType -eq 'continuousIntegration'}

    if ($trigger) {
        $trigger.branchFilters = $branchNames | % {"+refs/heads/$_/*"}
        Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://devops.domain.com/Collection/Project/_apis/build/definitions/$($definition.id)?api-version=5.0" -Method PUT -ContentType application/json -Body ($definitionToUpdate | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10) -Header $header
    }
}
```

The code checks that the CI trigger exists before updating its branch filters.

Comment: Great catch! I not tried the definitions options, I started with get the build definition and this is the reason I succeeded.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk I've upvoted your answer as it infers this but you didn't state what `$url` is. Also, prepending `+refs/heads/` to the branch names was useful info. Feel free to upvote mine! ;)

Comment: you deserve it :)

Answer (score 3):

The `triggers` is array so you can't just edit it, you need to edit the `triggers[0]`, the same thing it's the `branchFilters`, you need to edit the `branchFilters[0]`. also, you don't need to touch in the `triggerType`.

All the above it's assuming that there is already a trigger in the build and you want to edit it, not add a new trigger section.

There is also a tricky thing in the `branchFilters` array, if you have only 1 branch (`master` for example) and you want to add another branch you need to add it to the array and not just edit the `branchFilters[0]` value.

Last thing that should be fixed is the branches value, it should be `+refs/heads/branchName` and not just the branch name.

So, I have a pipeline with `test` branch trigger and I succeeded to edit the trigger to `master` and `feature/*` with this script:

```
# I get only one definition and update him, not iterate all my definitions
$definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get

# Change the branch trigger from "test" to "master"
$definition.triggers[0].branchFilters[0] = "+refs/heads/master"

# Add another branch trigger - "feature/*"
$definition.triggers[0].branchFilters[0] += "+refs/heads/feature/*"

$body = $definition | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
Write-Host $body

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -ContentType application/json -Body $body
```

Comment: I just noticed I was getting this error on my original code: `"The property 'triggers' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."` Your code in fact results in this error: `Cannot index into a null array.` I'm not sure why it would work for you, but it seems I must forcibly add a member to the JSON object using `Add-Member -NotePropertyName triggers -Force` and set a value using `-NotePropertyValue`. I've updated the question to this effect. But I am still getting the error mentioned when calling `Invoke-RestMethod`.

Comment: omfg, i was struggling with this nearly to 4 hours.
I did notice that it was an array, i was getting same error "cannot be set to this object".
TY very much !

Answer (score 1):

Here is slide correction that works for me,

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$token = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalAccessToken)"))
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic $token")
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$definitions = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://devops.domain.com/Collection/Project/_apis/build/definitions" -Method GET -Headers $headers

ForEach ($definition in $definitions.value) {
    $definition.triggers = (@{ triggerType = 'continuousIntegration'; branchFilters = 'master', 'feature/*' })
    $definition.revision++

    $body = $definition | ConvertTo-Json
    Write-Host $body

    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://devops.domain.com/Collection/Project/_apis/build/definitions/$($definition.id)?api-version=5.0" -Method PUT -ContentType application/json -Body $body -Headers $headers
}
```

Comment: Please see my comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56855732/update-build-definition-using-azure-devops-rest-api-in-powershell/56866206#comment100317555_56866176).