# Is it possible to clone or export\import an azure release pipeline programmatically

Tags: .net, powershell, azure-devops

Trying to create a release pipeline programmatically, is it possible to export or clone an existing pipeline into yaml through PowerShell commands or something?

Attached screenshot from Azure DevOps:
[image: Attached screenshot from Azure DevOps]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this with the REST API:

- the [GET request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) should bring you the JSON representation of the [pipeline definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#pipeline)

  - its 'configuration' property is of type [Pipeline Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#pipelineconfiguration)
- copy the 'configuration' part of the response, modify as needed for a new pipeline, and feed the result as an input to the [POST request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

It seems that the whole process can be wrapped in a PowerShell script. I don't have the env at hand to try this out and send you the exact snippets, but hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to export or clone an existing pipeline **into yaml** through PowerShell commands or something?

For the **Release pipeline**, I am afraid you could not export or clone an existing **Release** pipeline **into yaml** through PowerShell commands or something. That because MS provide the Multi-stage YAML pipelines for CI and CD, So, there is no separate YAML mode for release pipeline. We could not export or clone an existing pipeline **into yaml** for release pipeline.

For the **Build pipeline**, we could use the REST API [Yaml - Get](http://GET%20https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/build/definitions/%7BdefinitionId%7D/yaml?api-version=6.1-preview.1) to get the YAML for the build pipeline:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}/yaml?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

And how to use the YAML to create a new build pipeline, you could refer below thread:

[Azure DevOps create build definition via REST API given existing YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59058254/azure-devops-create-build-definition-via-rest-api-given-existing-yaml)